# Create words' stream using scanner

Tags: java, loops, java-stream, builder, cpu-word

There is needed to return a stream of all words that have 3letters and more from a file. Is there better way then following, maybe using Stream.iterate:

```
private Stream<String> getWordsStream(String path){
    Stream.Builder<String> wordsStream = Stream.builder();
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner s = new Scanner(inputStream);
    s.useDelimiter("([^a-zA-Z])");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{3,})");
    while ((s.hasNext())){
        if(s.hasNext(pattern)){
            wordsStream.add(s.next().toUpperCase());
        }
        else {
            s.next();
        }
    }
    s.close();
    return wordsStream.build();
}
```

Comment: Which Java version?

Comment: Did you mean to call `s.next(pattern)`?

Comment: Maybe reading the entire stream as a string, then splitting it with a space (or whatever you're using), then checking each for their length.

Comment: Java 9.  I mean: is it possible to write this method more closely to stream style, without while loop at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Files.lines()` and a `Pattern`:

```
private static final Pattern SPACES = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]+");

public static Stream<String> getWordStream(String path) throws IOException{
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(path))
        .flatMap(SPACES::splitAsStream)
        .filter(word -> word.length() >= 3);
}
```

Comment: There is tested for a book with 105 K words. This method is the fastest, took 0.29s.

Comment: @Alex well, this method also skips the conversion to uppercase. Further, your original code was designed to process words consisting of ASCII letters only, whereas this code treats everything separated by a single space character as a word.

Comment: Pattern was changed to    
Pattern SPACES = Pattern.compile("([^a-zA-Z])");

Comment: @Alex You should probably use `Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]+")` (notice the `+` at the end). So you won't get "empty" words, e.g a text like: `"I have 100 dollars"` would produce an array: `["I", "have", "", "", "", "", "dollars"]` with the current pattern

Answer (score 5):

The worst part of your code is the following part

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Scanner s = new Scanner(inputStream);
```

So when the file is absent, you will print the `FileNotFoundException` stack trace and proceed with a `null` input stream, leading to a `NullPointerException`. Instead of requiring the caller to deal with a spurious `NullPointerException`, you should declare the `FileNotFoundException` in the method signature. Otherwise, return an empty stream in the erroneous case.

But you don’t need to contruct a `FileInputStream` at all, as `Scanner` offers constructors accepting a `File` or `Path`. Combine this with the capability of returning a stream of matches (since Java 9) and you get:

```
private Stream<String> getWordsStream(String path) {
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(Paths.get(path));
        return s.findAll("([a-zA-Z]{3,})").map(mr -> mr.group().toUpperCase());
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return Stream.empty();
    }
}
```

or preferably

```
private Stream<String> getWordsStream(String path) throws IOException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(Paths.get(path));
    return s.findAll("([a-zA-Z]{3,})").map(mr -> mr.group().toUpperCase());
}
```

You don’t even need `.useDelimiter("([^a-zA-Z])")` here, as skipping all nonmatching stuff is the default behavior.

Closing the returned `Stream` will also close the `Scanner`.

So the caller should use it like this

```
try(Stream<String> s = getWordsStream("path/to/file")) {
    s.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: There is tested for a book with 105 K words. This method took about 0.6s.

Answer (score 0):

Thre're much easier approach: read lines from file to the `Stream` and filter it with required condition (e.g. length >= 3). `Files.lines()` has lazy loading, so it does not ready all words from the file at the beginning, it does it every time when next word is required

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    getWordsStream(Paths.get("d:/words.txt")).forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static Stream<String> getWordsStream(Path path) throws IOException {
    final Scanner scan = new Scanner(path);

    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<String>(Long.MAX_VALUE,
            Spliterator.DISTINCT | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE | Spliterator.NONNULL | Spliterator.ORDERED) {
        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> action) {
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                String word = scan.next();

                // you can use RegExp if you have more complicated condition
                if (word.length() < 3)
                    continue;

                action.accept(word);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }, false).onClose(scan::close);
}
```

Comment: and `lines()` will return a stream of **words**? would be a very bad name for such method - maybe Java 9, but for sure in Java 11 it is returning a stream of **lines**

Comment: It returns lines that have more then 3 letter symbols in any Java.

I have an unprepared text. So needs a loop again for finding all matches in a line.

Comment: well, actually `lines()` returns all lines, not only the ones with more than 3 letter. It's `getWordsStream()` that returns the lines with 3 or more letters. But question is about **words** with 3 or more letters, not about **lines**

Comment: With [tag:Java-11], you need not to change the signature of that method and can use `Files.lines(Path.of(path))` instead.

Comment: Fixed. Same lazy load approach. Pease a cake.

Comment: After your edit, the introduction does not match the code, as it is neither “much easier” nor dealing `Files.lines()`.  Further, there is no guaranty that the caller will consume all elements, the stream might perform a short-circuiting operation, so it’s not enough to close the resource when reaching the end of the stream. You need to chain an `.onClose(scan::close)`. But note that for Java 9, this work has been done inside `Scanner` already, so [you can simply use `findAll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388608/2711488)…

Comment: I do not use Java9, so can't say about findAll

Comment: @Holger thanks for `onClose` I thought about correct stream close as well